# correct verb form: listen to me talking or listen to me talk

Tags: present-tense

(1) Nobody listened to me talking about UFOs.

(2) Nobody listened to me talk about UFOs.

Which verb form is correct?

Comment: If you want more than "Yes these are both correct" answer, you should some more details or context

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

(1) Nobody listened to me **talking** about UFOs. (in the middle of talking, not complete action)

(2) Nobody listened to me **talk** about UFOs. (complete action from beginning to end)

After hear, see, **listen to**, notice, feel, watch etc. we can use an ing-form (after the object). We can also use an infinitive without to (after the object).

Answer (score 0):

They both are correct and mean basically the same thing.